# Is it appropriate to create a Service explicitly via constructor?

Tags: android

I know that all application components shouldn't be instantiated directly and I should use `startService` or `bindService` for interacting with `Service`. But in Google sample showing how to implement in-app billing version 2 I can see that `Service` is created directly in Dungeons.java at line 259:

```
mBillingService = new BillingService();
mBillingService.setContext(this);
```

`BillingService` class extends `android.app.Service` and is registered in manifest as service.

But `BillingService` object is just created instead of binding. So I wonder was it a bug in official sample or is it really suitable way for local services?

Comment: Does BillingService extends Server/IntentService from Android? Or is it a stand alone class that just needs a reference to the context? This should work since the Service lifecycle won't be handled by the framework. Do you have the example url ?

Comment: Yeah. That seems odd to me. You'd have to register the `Service` to the OS somehow so the OS knows to call it. I don't think there's a way to do it without doing `startService` or `bindService`. This is just an object reference to the class but the OS itself wouldn't know it exists.

Comment: @Robert, yes, BillingService extends Server and it is registered in AndroidManifest.xml as Service. [This](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) is a link, but I'm not sure if it is still possible to download it with SDK Manager as billing v2 is already deprecated.

Comment: @DeeV, I thought that may be `Service` ifself can register from constructor but seems that `BillingService` is described as `Service` component but actually treated as usual object.